# Create Oracle Procedure with rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

How do you create a procedure in Oracle with a select from rdsadmin?

**Environment:**
Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.4.0
AWS RDS

SQL query

```
 `SELECT * FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'));`
```

**Returns**

[image]
(fig.1)

Store Procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_LIST_DIR
IS
BEGIN

  SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'));

END SP_LIST_DIR;
```

How can I get the procedure to return the results from (fig.1)?

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Oracle does not have permissions to run RDSADMIN in a procedure.  Running this resolved the issue:

grant execute on rdsadmin.rds_file_util to < procedure owner >;

reference:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=893048